# gvim - omnicompletion on remote ftp crashes

Tags: crash, vim, omnicomplete

Hello I have a problem using latest vim with omnicompletion while editing a file that is located remotely on ftp.

```
 :e ftp-address//
```

it just hangs on "searching" and then outputs that it is missing a file after along time, the second time i try VIM crashes, 
i've tried to look up on :help and googled but it does not seems to be a common problem. But I would like any suggestions on it.

While using it localy it works great.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to whom this may interest.

After searching and consulting I've found that this happened because of vim trying to find information on the server which took a long trip back and fourth for each file.

I've found another setup for windows who works well:

There is a program called [winSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).
it isn't the only one but this does it's jobs perfectly.

anyway it has a feature to sync any changes done in a local directory and upload it to the FTP server.

i used all vim features locally and it works fast and good :)